# Providers in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, state-management

I am building a note app with details of title and description whereby my input comes from a textfield from an alertDialog popup. Unfortunately, the screen is blank.

This is my UserNotes

```
class UserNotes{
  String? title;
  String? descriptioin;


  UserNotes({required this.title,required this.descriptioin});

}
```

This is my provider

```
import 'package:notes_update/models/UserMethods.dart';
import 'package:notes_update/models/UserNotes.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
class ProviderData extends ChangeNotifier{
  List<UserNotes>_users=[];

  List<UserNotes> get newusers=>_users;

  IncomingData(){
    _users=GettingNotes().addDetails();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

This class returns a list of userNotes

```
import 'UserNotes.dart';

class GettingNotes{
String? newtitle;
String? description;
List<UserNotes> addDetails(){
  List<UserNotes>details=[];
  if(details.isEmpty){
    details.add(UserNotes(title:newtitle!,descriptioin:description! ));
  }

  return details;
}}
```

This is my UI

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:notes_update/models/UserMethods.dart';
import 'package:notes_update/models/UserNotes.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../Provider/Provder.dart';

class Notes extends StatefulWidget {
  createState() => _Notes();
}

class _Notes extends State<Notes> {
  var title;
  var description;
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Consumer<ProviderData>(builder:
              (BuildContext context, ProviderData value, Widget? child) {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: value.newusers.length,
                itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(value.newusers[index].title!),
                    leading: Text(value.newusers[index].descriptioin!),
                  );
                }));
          }),
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              FloatingActionButton(
                backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
                child: Center(
                    child: Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                  size: 40,
                )),
                onPressed: () => showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
                            title: Text('NOTES INFO'),
                            content: Column(
                              children: [
                                TextFormField(
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      hintText: 'Enter notes title',
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                                  onChanged: (value) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      description = value;
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height:50),
                                TextFormField(
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      hintText: 'Enter notes description',
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                                  onChanged: (value) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      description = value;
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            actions: <Widget>[
                              TextButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    GettingNotes().newtitle = title;
                                    GettingNotes().description = description;
                                  });
                                  Navigator.pop(context);
                                },
                                child: Text('Save Data'),
                              ),
                              TextButton(
                                  onPressed: () {}, child: Text('Cancel'))
                            ])),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If there is any code mistake, let me know.

I passed on the value of my TextForm using setState to change the current value of my title and description and I expected a list based on my title and description.

Answer (score 1):

**Two mistakes:**

1. In both the `TextFormField` you are setting `description` value and `title` value is never set.
2. In `onPressed` you are creating new instance of `UserNotes` class instead of `GettingNotes` class, and adding it to the list of notes in `ProviderData` class.

And create a `addNote` function, where in you add the `note` to the list.

Updated Provider Code:

```
  void addNote({
    required String title,
    required String description,
  }) {
    _users.add(UserNotes(title: title, descriptioin: description));
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Updated UI code:

```
                onPressed: () => showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
                    title: Text('NOTES INFO'),
                    content: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        TextFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: 'Enter notes title',
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          ),
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              title = value; //  set title here
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20),
                        TextFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: 'Enter notes description',
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          ),
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              description = value;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    actions: <Widget>[
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (title != null && description != null) {
                            Provider.of<ProviderData>(context, listen: false) // call it this way
                                .newusers
                                .add(UserNotes(
                                  title: title,
                                  description: description,
                                ));  //       
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          }
                        },
                        child: Text('Save Data'),
                      ),
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                        child: Text('Cancel'),
                      ),
                    ],
```

Comment: Thank you very much.But please i would like you  to kindly clarify my thought if the value in my onchanged parameter is the current state of what the user will type in the textfTield?Thank you

Comment: Yes in the onchanged, you get the current state i.e latest updated value which the user has typed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.But please if the value represent the current state of the input which has been assigned to the title why should i set title again?

Comment: because it is there just in the parameter of `onChanged` if you want it to be used elsewhere you need to assign to some variable, so you are assigning

Comment: Thanks.So please do you mean i.e String title='Church Service' before the onchanged?